# Unable to align the button inside the input

Tags: html, css

I want to create an input that contains a button that has an arrow down so the user can click on it to open a list or close it. I can't put the button inside the input, what do i miss here?

```css
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.combobox-input {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #828995;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}

.combobox-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(...);
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div className="input-wrapper">
  <input className="combobox-input"/>
  <button className="combobox-arrow" ></button> 
</div>
```

Comment: you have no `position: absolute` on your button

Comment: Why would you want to put the button _inside_ the input (as opposed to “next to it”)? It would obstruct the text in the input box underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it suits your need:
(you can modify the snippet code as per your need)

```js
document.getElementById('caret').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // your code here if you want to add some logic
});
```

```css
button#caret {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.input-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<label>List of places<br/>
  <div class="datalist-wrap">
    <div class="input-wrap">    
      <input id="placesText" type="text" name="places" list="places"/>
      <button id="caret"> &#9660;</button>
    </div>
    <datalist id="places">
      <label>Select from the list:
        <select name="places" id="select">
        <option value="A"></option>
        <option value="B"></option>
        <option value="C"></option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </datalist>
  </div>
</label>
```